# Transition Animation Doesn't Work

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, css-transitions

Why transition animation doesn't work?
I use display, visibility and opacity, but it doesn't work.

It's simple example code below

```js
$('button').click(function(){
  $('.block').toggleClass('block-open');
})
```

```css
.block {
  display: none;
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  background-color: red;
  width: 250px;
  height: 250px;
  -webkit-transition: all ease-out 5s;
  -moz-transition: all ease-out 5s;
  -o-transition: all ease-out 5s;
  transition: all ease-out 5s;
}
  
.block-open {
  display: block;
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
  -webkit-transition: all ease-out 5s;
  -moz-transition: all ease-out 5s;
  -o-transition: all ease-out 5s;
  transition: all ease-out 5s;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>Toggle</button>
<div class="block"></div>
```

Comment: It's because of display: none rule in the .block class

Comment: remove display none and bock

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Remove   display: block; & display:none;

**Check Below  Working Snippet**

```js
$('button').click(function(){
  $('.block').toggleClass('block-open');
})
```

```css
.block {
  
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  background-color: red;
  width: 250px;
  height: 250px;
  -webkit-transition: all ease-out 5s;
  -moz-transition: all ease-out 5s;
  -o-transition: all ease-out 5s;
  transition: all ease-out 5s;
}
  
.block-open {

  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
  -webkit-transition: all ease-out 5s;
  -moz-transition: all ease-out 5s;
  -o-transition: all ease-out 5s;
  transition: all ease-out 5s;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>Toggle</button>
<div class="block"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this,

```js
$('button').click(function(){
  $('.block').toggleClass('block-open');
})
```

```css
.block {
  display: block;
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  background-color: red;
  width: 250px;
  height: 250px;
  -webkit-transition: all ease-out 5s;
  -moz-transition: all ease-out 5s;
  -o-transition: all ease-out 5s;
  transition: all ease-out 5s;
}
  
.block-open {
  display: block;
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
  -webkit-transition: all ease-out 5s;
  -moz-transition: all ease-out 5s;
  -o-transition: all ease-out 5s;
  transition: all ease-out 5s;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>Toggle</button>
<div class="block"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Just Remove `display: block;` and `display:none;`**

```
.block {

  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  background-color: red;
  width: 250px;
  height: 250px;
  -webkit-transition: all ease-out 5s;
  -moz-transition: all ease-out 5s;
  -o-transition: all ease-out 5s;
  transition: all ease-out 5s;

}

.block-open {

  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
  -webkit-transition: all ease-out 5s;
  -moz-transition: all ease-out 5s;
  -o-transition: all ease-out 5s;
  transition: all ease-out 5s;

}
```

Full code :

```js
$('button').click(function(){

  $('.block').toggleClass('block-open');
  
})
```

```css
.block {

  visibility: hidden;
  
  opacity: 0;
  
  background-color: red;
  
  width: 250px;
  
  height: 250px;
  
  -webkit-transition: all ease-out 5s;
  
  -moz-transition: all ease-out 5s;
  
  -o-transition: all ease-out 5s;
  
  transition: all ease-out 5s;
  
}
  
.block-open {

  visibility: visible;
  
  opacity: 1;
  
  -webkit-transition: all ease-out 5s;
  
  -moz-transition: all ease-out 5s;
  
  -o-transition: all ease-out 5s;
  
  transition: all ease-out 5s;
  
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button>Toggle</button>

<div class="block"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

CSS property `display:none;` does not actually support transition.

You can use `overflow:none;` and `height:0;`.

Here is the demo link: https://jsfiddle.net/sujan_mhrzn/76tf7ds9/